# Run Flash content ( web game ) inside Java application?

Tags: java, webview, chromium-embedded, jxbrowser, embedded-flashplayer

How can I Load a web game that need flash to run ? I try many version of JxBrowser which support Flash but haven't success.

I am not obliged to stay on JxBrowser if you have solutions with another tool.

Answer (score 0):

The support of [Adobe Flash was removed in Chromium 88](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/2021/03/03/flash-end-of-life.html). Thereafter, it's not supported in JxBrowser starting from 7.13.

You may try running [JxBrowser 7.12](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2020/v7-12.html) or earlier. However, we strongly recommend using the latest JxBrowser version as they have the latest security fixes from Chromium.